# Rest API | Single Verb performs CRUD?

Tags: architecture, rest, api

I have some logic that needs to be called by multiple applications ( mobile, web, ...). Instead of duplicating this logic, I thought of putting it in a Rest API so that I could call it from any of the applications.

The "logic" that I wish to put on my Rest API basically reads, creates and deletes multiple rows from multiple databases all at once.

But, since this "logic" executes multiple actions at the same time ( it doesn't only "GET" or "PUT" ), I feel like calling this method using the "GET" or "POST" Verbs would be weird.

So, my question is:

Is a Rest API really a good solution for this problem ?

If so, what would be the best way to handle this situation ? Should I just call it using whatever HTTP Verb I want ?

Comment: `The "logic" that I wish to put on my Rest API basically reads, creates and deletes multiple rows from multiple databases all at once.` -- You're looking for POST.   GET and PUT don't do this.

Comment: So you mean that it would be fine to call this action with the POST verb ?

Comment: You need to be more specific with your inquiries.  "Fine" is not a sufficient distinction.

Comment: My question is: Would it be a good practice to use the POST HTTP Verb for an action that does multiple things such as creating, updating and getting data ?

Comment: "Good" is not specific enough.  What does "good" mean to you?

Comment: Is this what is done in the industry, is it "normal" to do so.

Comment: What is "normally" done is to evaluate the specific software requirements and come up with a design that is consistent with those requirements and adequately fulfills its objectives.

Comment: That is exactly why I asked my question. I want to know what others would do in this situation.

Comment: Read [this article](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/03/02/best-practices-for-rest-api-design/) for a basic understanding of REST architectural style.  From the description you've provided, based on the article's description of REST principles, the answer to your question "Would it be a good practice to use the POST HTTP Verb for an action that does multiple things such as creating, updating and getting data" would be "no", because none of the verbs do "multiple things."  They map to individual CRUD operations.

Comment: But all that means is that your API is probably not going to be REST-conformant, and *that is OK.*  Most web API's in use at the largest companies (Facebook, Twitter, etc.) don't actually conform to Roy Fielding's notion of REST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If so, what would be the best way to handle this situation ? Should I just call it using whatever HTTP Verb I want ?

How would you do this with web pages?

There would probably be an HTML page with a link on it, where the link would say something like "to do everything at once, fill in this form".  The link brings you to the form, which would have a submit button, and possibly some input controls to collect data.  When the user clicks the submit button, the information is gathered up into an HTTP request and sent to the server.

The server then "does the thing".

Based on your description, this action doesn't sound like an [essentially read-only](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.2.1) operation; you wouldn't want anything to happen each time Google indexes your web page.

Therefore, in this design, the appropriate HTTP method to use for the form submission is POST.  [That's okay.](https://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2009/it-is-okay-to-use-post)

Answer (score -3):

Instead of randomly calling everything at once, I think you should break down your processing with steps, so that both you and the computer knows what's happening.

The reason there are GET,POST,PUT,DELETE and not a single verb available means that the software protocol wants us to use these different commands based on necessity.

A Get request doesn't tinker with database but POST,PUT & DELETE do.

May be go through the documentation for the language you are running.

I have a strong feeling that even though you could solve your problem with a single verb, as the user interaction grows, it has a high likelihood of severely damaging your database and application because of the various possibilities that you can no longer measure because you used a single verb for everything.

Comment: You can write an entire API using POST, and do it *safely.*  I've seen it done before.